# Redis using in application

Tags: node.js, redis, storage, node-redis

Which is the preferred way to use the Redis throughout the application,

**Singleton** (one open connection throughout the application) OR
**Scope** ( Create the connection open and close always we need - multiple open and multiple closed connections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open a single client connection using one of the leading node.js clients like: [ioredis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis) or [node-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)